# Add Excel to sharepoint service programatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, asp.net

I have a Excel with `Pivot charts` on my client (**Not on sharepoint Server**). Is there any way to upload it using sharepoint services by `C#`?

thanks

Comment: just to clarify - are you looking to upload your excel file to SharePoint library or is your question about Excel Services?

Comment: I created a report using service.Now I want to upload it to `Document` section in my sharepoint site. I want to upload it programatically. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for upload using server side coode, here's TechNet article for SharePoint 2010, I've taken bits and bobs from it before and should give you a generic idea on how to accomplish your task: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms454491(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms454491%28v=office.14%29.aspx)